# How to read a string into a vector

Tags: c++, vector, io

I need help reading a string into a vector:

```
vector <string> FileSplitting (vector <string> signalFileNames){

vector<string> signalFileExtensions;

for (int i=0;i<signalFileNames.size();i++){
    unsigned found = (unsigned int) signalFileNames[i].find_last_of(".");
    string fileExtension = signalFileNames[i].substr(found+1);
}
return signalFileExtensions;

}
```

before the return statement, I want to read the fileExtension string into the vector signalFileExtensions. I was thinking about writing the following code to do that:

```
fileExtension = signalFileExtensions[i];
```

I wasn't sure if this was right because I may need to read the string into the vector into the vector.

Comment: [`push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back)

Comment: You just "add()" elements to a [C++ vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/), usually with `myvector.push_back(mystring);`  You can also `assign()`, `emplace()`, `swap()`, etc.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious   I was aware of the much back method. I thought I needed to do something else as well. Thanks!

Comment: @ForrestChanningHunter Cf c++ reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < signalFileNames.size(); i++){
        unsigned found = (unsigned int) signalFileNames[i].find_last_of(".");
        string fileExtension = signalFileNames[i].substr(found+1);
        signalFileExtensions.push_back(fileExtension);
}
return signalFileExtensions;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use push_back() or emplace_back(). The latter was introduced in C++11